# A nonlinear differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

We are to solve

$$y=(y'-1)\cdot e^{y'}$$

Let $p=y'$, so $$y= (p-1)\cdot e^p$$
Differentiate: $$dy=(e^p + pe^p-e^p)dp=pe^p\, dp$$
From $$dx=\dfrac{dy}{p}=e^p\,dp$$
I find $$x=\int(e^p)dp=e^p$$.but the answer on my book is $$y=[\ln(x-c)-1]\cdot(x-c)$$
Help?

Comment: What makes you think you can differentiate w.r.t. different variables on different sides of the same equation? This is why it helps to be more explicit in your work, so you avoid making such mistakes.

Comment: If we let the independent variable be $x$, we know that $p$ must be a function of $x$ as well.  Thus, you need a chain rule step in your 3rd line of math text above.

Comment: OP actually hasn't done that. They've just written $y'$ instead of $\mathrm d y$.

Comment: @Sharkos who are you talking to? Me or oldrinb?

Comment: Both of you. In terms of differential forms, the argument is watertight, it's just the third line should begin $\mathrm d y$ and have a $\mathrm d p$  in the middle.

Comment: @uer I've learned about ordinary differential equations from books I've downloaded online.

Comment: Sorry then :) good luck.

Comment: @uer are you claiming $e^p\ dp=dx$?

Comment: @Sharkos Ah!  That's what was tripping me up.  I didn't see the $dp$ in the middle, which threw me.

Comment: It's sloppy notation but good maths.

Comment: This answer is missing the constant solution $y = -1$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$x=e^p \implies p=\mathrm d y/\mathrm d x = \log x$$

You need to integrate this for $y=y(x)$.

---

Note that to get the constant shift, you should use $x =\int e^p\mathrm d p = e^p+c$. You should also go back and check the original equation to make sure you haven't got any incorrect solutions by accident. This is always a good idea with nonlinear equations. (The point is that you differentiated a first order equation with one arbitrary constant so you introduced an extra fictitious one.)

Comment: when I integrate this I get x ln(x) - x + C. :/

Comment: Nearly there! I've pointed out how to get the constant shift they have and eliminate the one you have.

Comment: I don't know who you are but I will find you and I will marry you.

Comment: My details are on my website, but an upvote will do. ;)

Comment: Also see comments on your question about the third line being wrong.

Comment: Hahaha finally someone with a sense of humour here! I will upvote it instantly ;)

Comment: I cant upvote this because im not logged in :/ but I accepted this as a final answer :)

Comment: Thanks again Carl,and yes,I noted the error in the third line.